# What properties does an object oriented language have?

Tags: programming-languages, game-development, scripting

I'm currently working on a game and wanted to add some scripting support. Due to trying to keep the entire codebase in managed c# (Excluding Monogame), I am using a custom language for the scripting (No managed only implementations of Lua exist...except AluminumLua which is incomplete).

In such a language, basic provisions would need to exist. These would include:

- Objects / Properties / Variables
- floats and strings
- Functions
- Conditionals
- Loops

Am I missing any major parts of a basic object oriented language?

**EDIT:**
As comments have pointed out, I would be far better finishing the incomplete implementation of Lua for C# rather than designing my own language...which is what I am going to do. However, I am still curious what the properties of an object oriented language are. **So, what properties does an OO language have?**

Some definitions of object orientation (again, decided in the comments):

Combining the state of an object with it's behavior.

An object oriented language is is a method of combining the state of an object (it's properties) with behavior (functions).

Object orientation is defining data (like a C struct) and providing specific methods to interact with it (the function ChangeValue), rather than give the person using that code the ability to change any part, including 'internal' components.

Object orientation is just a way to sort the data (that will be represented in binary) more clearly to a programmer and protecting against incorrect use (e.g. setting a char instead of a byte into a function).

Comment: First, define object oriented...

Comment: Add as much as you are willing to support in your game. Starting small and growing the language will be easier to manage.

Comment: High-order functions with lexical scope. An object is just a collection of functions where each function takes the collection as its first (usually implicit) argument. The logical next step is a [record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_%28computer_science%29) type, because arrays or tuples aren't very user-friendly ways of bundling functions together.

Comment: I think it would be easier to complete the partial implementation of Lua than to build your own language.  Did you check for a Javascript interpreter for your environment?

Comment: Object oriented or not - libraries, debuggers, and other tools. Oh and documentation, which is a good reason to consider implementing a superset (ideal) or subset (ok) of an existing language for scripting. I'll point out that the partial implementation of Lua is further along than any language that is currently in a pre-planning phase.

Comment: @MichaelT Would you please define object oriented for us ?

Comment: @user61852 *snort* I'm not even going to try. [C2.com Object Oriented Programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObjectOrientedProgramming) is a good read. The best minimal definition on that page is probably 'combining state with behavior' but that just sounds a bit too hand wavery for me. I've seen people argue that $lang is OO and not OO and that some definition is or is not proper because it includes excludes some other feature that they consider to be key to OO. [Nobody agrees on what OO is](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NobodyAgreesOnWhatOoIs) and [Defs of OO](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DefinitionsForOo)

Comment: I do agree with what has been said about the time spent completing an implementation vs. an entire new language...so I'm just going to try and build a more solid implementation of AluminumLua. Is there a way to close the question or is it supposed to be deleted or...?

Comment: @MichaelT Do you think OO languages exist?

Comment: @user61852 I disagree. Object oriented languages do exist, there is just no exact, widely agreed upon definition of a OO language. What you're saying is that since not everyone agrees about religion, that there is no such thing as religion.

Comment: @user2841239 What would be one of those OO languages you say exist ?

Comment: @user2841239 there are two close votes pending on it. You could flag it with a custom mod message stating your wishes. I'd enjoy seeing you in [chat] (the whiteboard) if you wish to discuss the true Scotsman of OO or pointers on language design.

Comment: @user61852 C#, Python, Lua, and many more. In its simplest form, all an object oriented language is is a method of combining the state of an object (it's properties) with behavior (functions). Object orientation is defining data (like a C struct) and providing specific methods to interact with it (the function ChangeValue), rather than leave the data open for modifying any component of it. Basically, object orientation is just a way to sort the data (that will be represented in binary) more clearly to a programmer and protecting against incorrect use (e.g. setting a char instead of a byte).

Comment: @MichaelT Unfortunately, I do not have the 20 reputation necessary to be on Programmers Chat. Would it be a better idea to flag it or wait for the close votes to go through or leave it open as a question about the general properties of an OO language?

Comment: @MichaelT user2841239, above, gave a definition, and examples that could be good enough to give OP a context of what OO is.

Comment: @user61852 user2841239 / me is the original poster...Should this be added to the original post as an edit / definition?

Comment: @user2841239 Yes! That way you accommodate to MichaelT's comment asking you to define OO.

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped..." ([help/dont-ask]). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: `Object orientation is defining data (like a C struct) and providing specific methods to interact with it (the function ChangeValue), rather than give the person using that code the ability to change any part, including 'internal' components.` That's not an object, it's an abstract data type. An object is a collection (e.g. a `struct`) of functions, but C doesn't have closures, so you can't create objects that hide (non-static) data. Function pointers can only refer to global variables or static variables. And without data hiding, what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core idea behind object-oriented programming is the *encapsulation* and *information hiding* of data and functions that operate on that data within *objects*. Rather than building an open data structure (think traditional C `struct`) and passing a pointer around to functions, you put the functions in the structure and call those functions directly.

Everything else builds on these core concepts, but if I had to name the bare minimum that makes an OO language, encapsulation and information hiding are it.

- *[encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)* means some structure contains data and functions: they are *contained* by the object.
- *[Information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)* is the idea that an object's data is not directly accessible on the outside. It must be manipulated or used via its functions.

There are other features that are not core OO concepts but extend them in a way that is useful and are often included:

- *[Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)*: an object may *extend* another object, inheriting its data and functions and providing new ones. This is tied to the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) where a subclass must be able to take the place of a superclass. The idea here is that by extending a superclass, a class can define additional behavior or even change the superclass implementation as long as it adheres to the contract of its interface.
- *[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)*: related to inheritance, where subclasses have different behavior in accordance with a common interface. The idea is that (at least with static polymorphism, commonly found in Java, C# and C++) if you need an object that does something, you can take an object with a given interface and expect different behavior based on its implementation *and you don't care what the implementation is*.

Many languages add more and more features, but these are the basics.

Comment: If it were just encapsulation and data hiding, then FP fits the bill too with closures.

Comment: Encapsulation and Data Hiding are properties of Structured Programming, Modular Programming and Programming with Abstract Data Types as well. Inheritance is orthogonal to OO. Polymorphism is a *consequence* of OO. The distinguishing feature of OO is Procedural Data Abstraction, achieved through Messaging. See http://www.purl.org/stefan_ram/pub/doc_kay_oop_en, [The big idea is 'messaging'](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/squeak-dev/1998-October/017019.html), [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf), …

Comment: … [*Proposal for Simplified, Modern Definitions of "Object" and "Object Oriented"*](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/2012/07/proposal-for-simplified-modern.html), http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/253121/1352

Comment: A language without inheritance is not OO, period.

Answer (score -4):

properties of object oriented language are:

--> encapsulation
--> abstraction
--> Inheritance
--> polymorphism

Main Thing is Object and Classes

Any thing in Object oriented language converted into Objects

Comment: is this only your opinion or you can back it up somehow?